# How to access Ambiguous Column in SQL Query with SELECT *

Tags: sql-server, datatable, sql

When I execute Stored Procedure

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN BloodBankUser ON Users.UserID = BloodBankUser.UserID
```

It gives me result fine.

but now on .net side

```
dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
```

this gives me Address of table *BloodBankUser*

```
dt.Rows[0]["Users.Address"].ToString();
```

when I debug this statement it execute error

> Column 'Users.Address' does not
>   belong to table.

How can I get Value of Users.Address

Comment: Never use select * especially if you have a join. it is poor practice that wastes processing time.

Comment: I already knew solution to remove Select *. What if I want solution with SELECT *

Comment: Why should we give you a solution so you can continue to use a poor practice?

Comment: :) Its not practice dude its requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the first answer would be to change your SQL Query to specify a distinct name for each of your field, it is still possible to retrieve the table name associated with your field.

In this example, I am not filling a `DataTable` using a `DataAdapter`, but rather I am using the `SqlDataReader`.

**Be aware that this may fail if you are unable to retrieve the database schema for any reason**

When calling `ExecuteReader` on a `SqlCommand`, there is an overload that allows you to specify a `CommandBehavior`. In our case, the behavior that we want is `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo`.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
```

Now, on the reader, you can invoke the `GetSchemaTable` method. It returns a `DataTable` that contains the structure of your query.

```
var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

You can [read about that table on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx).

Our goal now is to match the field and table against its ordinal position in the column list. Three fields from the schema table are relevant to your interest:

- ColumnName
- BaseTableName
- ColumnOrdinal

You can then create an extension method to do that reading:

```
public static T Field<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, DataTable schema, string table, string field)
{
    // Search for the ordinal that match the table and field name
    var row = schema.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("BaseTableName") == table && r.Field<string>("ColumnName") == field);
    var ordinal = row.Field<int>("ColumnOrdinal");

    return (T)reader.GetValue(ordinal);
}
```

You can then call that extension method

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN BloodBankUser ON Users.UserID = BloodBankUser.UserID;", connection))
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
    {
        var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Field<string>(schema, "Users", "Address"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for unnecessary workaround for bad practice. What if Ordinal position changes? What if caller does not have VIEW DEFINITION? A stoerd proc is designed to obscure base tables

Comment: That's why I introduced the answer like I did followed by the warning in bold. Concerning the ordinal position, that's exactly what this code is doing: finding it. And beside, this is what the OP asked: read his last comment in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the FIELD in the output (Select FIELDNAME as NEWNAME)

Comment: Yep, if he had specified the columns to begin with and renamed any with the same name in both tables as he should have, this would not be a problem.

Comment: I already knew solution to remove Select *. What if I want solution with SELECT *

Answer (score 1):

You specify the column names rather than use `SELECT * FROM`  You will then be able to do the following

```
Select User.Username,
       User.Address as 'UserAddress',
       BloodBankUser.Address as 'BloodbankAddress'

FROM Users 
INNER JOIN BloodBankUser ON Users.UserID = BloodBankUser.UserID
```

Comment: I already knew solution to remove Select *. What if I want solution with SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of `*` in `SELECT` queries. Select only the columns you need and name them explicitly to avoid ambiguity,

Comment: I already knew solution to remove Select *. What if I want solution with SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

Insead of `SELECT *...` specify the columns you want explicitly, and alias those that may duplicate

```
SELECT Users.Address as UsersAddress
```